# How to enable powertools in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, yum, dnf

I have recently started working with CentOS 7 on a VM and I'm finding a problem with enabling powertools repository. I tried different methods described in CentOS 8 resources but none of them seems to work.

Normally, this should work:

```
dnf install epel-release
dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools
```

*I have also tried Powertools and crb

The error I get is:

```
Error: No matching repo to modify: powertools.
```

Here is my list of repositories:

```
$ dnf repolist
repo id                          repo name                                          status
base                             CentOS-7 - Base                                    10,072
centos-sclo-rh                   CentOS-7 - SCLo rh                                 8,112
*epel                            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64     13,752
extras                           CentOS-7 - Extras                                  516
updates                          CentOS-7 - Updates                                 4,244
```

*I also have copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:cottsay:devtoolset-8-make-nonblocking

I also have searched in the list of available packages under epel repo but couldn't find powertools (nor Powertools or crb):

```
sudo yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="epel" list available | grep 'powertools'
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories

> PowerTools - **Available only for CentOS8**, the PowerTools repository provides most of the developer tools. Disabled by default

Comment: I didn't notice that. Thanks @ron

Comment: Is there a similar repository providing development tools for Centos 7?

Comment: I've only used the repo's that are listed in that wiki, the main ones being **EPEL**, **RPMfusion_free** and **SCL**.  The *Software Collections Library" might be what you are looking for.  Consider asking this at forums.centos.org

Comment: I've also never used RHEL/CentOS 8,  I am on 7

Comment: I think `devtoolset`, what will give you GCC 11 for example, comes from SCL.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Thanks !